# Монгозадачность в консольной программе на C++

Tags: многопоточность, c++

Доброго вам времени суток! Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли в консольной программе добиться выполнения одновременно двух действий? То есть: есть программа-сервер (консольная, на С++), можно ли сделать так чтобы во время работы программы можно было вводить ей какие то команды (типо   меню)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, потоки работают одинаково вне зависимости от того, ваша программа консольная или имеет графический интерфейс.

Например:

```
void commandExecutor(Command* pCommand)
{
    pCommand->Run();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Menu menu;
    while (true)
    {
        menu.Display();
        Choice choice = menu.GetUserChoice();
        Command* pCmd = new Command(choice);
        std::thread* pt = new std::thread(commandExecutor, pCmd);
        // save pt for future reference
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://bitbybit.ru/article/146 я здесь нашел и попробовал, четко получилось! Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: А ты не знаешь как сделать что то типо кнопки в консоли!?

Comment: @Itachi779: в консоли — никак, там только буквы. Можно нарисовать кнопку псевдографикой :)

     ╔════════╗ 
     ║   OK   ║
     ╚════════╝ 

Но нажиматься она не будет, понятно.

Comment: Но я видел консольную программу в которой были кнопки!

Comment: @Itachi779: программа, которая стартует как консольная, может открыть окно, как и любая другая программа. Но кнопки будут уже не в консоли, а в окне.

Comment: Может то какой-нибудь порт турбовижна был :)

Comment: @klopp: ну или так :-)

Comment: @Itachi779, можете попробовать http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses